# Premium vs plain gas consumption on long trip

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-consumption, gasoline

I mostly ride my motorcycle on long trips distances of 200-250km with an average 100-120km/h speeds and using almost exclusively premium gasoline. My motorcycle is a Yamaha Fazer which does not REQUIRE premium gas but it has a somewhat "sportier orientation" motor. 
In Greece this is marketed as 100octane fuel but its well known in many cases to be a normal 95oct gasoline with additives that raise the octanes (maybe up to 97-98???)

The cost difference between normal grade and premium grade fuel in my country is about 12% (example prices 1,64E/lt for plain and 1,84E/lt for premium)
I have been told in many occasions that it is more cost efficient to use premium gas while traveling but after a couple of trips with plain fuel i can only notice a slight difference (increase) in consumption.

I understand how hard it is to make an accurate assumption while so many factors can be involved but i tried the same route (Patras-Athens 220km) carrying the same equipment filling from the same gas station and successfully tried to maintain my RPM on 5.5K throughout both trips. 
While on plain i got a 5.25lt/100km and while on premium a 5.05lt/100km which (given the above prices) translates to 8.61E/100km for plain and 9.29E/100km for premium. 
So still i cannot see any actual cost saving in using premium gas. 
Am i missing something here? Is there ANY occasion where using premium would actually prove to be more cost efficient???

Comment: FZ8 Fazer 2012 non ABS European model

Comment: No. Serious research showed about a 1/2 to 1 % ( depending on engine , etc) improvement in mpg for premium . This was determined to be because the components of the premium  made it more dense . So on a mile /pound basis they were about the same.

Answer (score 0):

For your bike? Probably not!

Different engines/ECUs will respond differently though - as a rule of thumb if the engine is mapped primarily for higher RON fuel it will be far more efficient on it and vice versa.

You don't specify the model and year of your Fazer but IIRC the 600 has a CR of 12:1 and the 1000 is slightly lower (I want to say 11.something:1), which aren't particularly high in the grand scheme of things which is probably why it doesn't *require* the higher RON fuel.